# Is mongoose's connect a version specific?

Tags: mongoose, database-connection, freeze, deprecation-warning

The part `mongoose.connect` is giving me problems. If I don't include useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, running the app.js in terminal will give me DeprecationWarning about including these parts. However if I do add them, running app.js does nothing. It just freezes forever.

```js
//jshint esversion:6

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
});


//Schema is scaffolding of date. For instance here's one for fruits. 
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

//This part is also required for upper one to work. 
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "I loved it."
});

fruit.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
.catch(err => {
console.log("DB Connection Error: ${err.message}");
});
```

Comment: and then open a new terminal tab

Comment: in the new terminal $mongo....$use fruitsDB....$db.fruits.find()